# Spring nested ConfigurationProperties and Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to use nested ConfigurationProperties in spring boot which is works in java but not in kotlin. I have got the following lines in my app property:

```
cert.signing-cert.filePath=truststore.jks
cert.signing-cert.password=xxxx
cert.private-signing.filePath=sign_test.p12
cert.private-signing.password=xxxx
cert.private-encrpytion.filePath=encryption_test.p12
cert.private-encrpytion.password=xxx
```

And I created this structure to handle these properties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("cert")
class CertConfig {
    lateinit var signingCert: SigningCert
    lateinit var privateSigning: PrivateSigning
    lateinit var privateEncrpytion: PrivateEncrpytion

    class SigningCert {
        lateinit var filePath: String
        lateinit var password: String
    }

    class PrivateSigning {
        lateinit var filePath: String
        lateinit var password: String
    }

    class PrivateEncrpytion {
        lateinit var filePath: String
        lateinit var password: String
    }
}
```

I added `kapt` plugin and dependecy to my `build.gradle.kts`

```
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.50"
...
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
```

And I got this exception when I run this code:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property signingCert has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I forgot to initialize the properties.

```
 var signingCert: SigningCert = SigningCert()
 var privateSigning: PrivateSigning = PrivateSigning()
 var privateEncrpytion: PrivateEncrpytion = PrivateEncrpytion()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can also be simplified to: `var signingCert = SigningCert()`